# Migrating from php mysql to sql server php

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857256/sql-compatibility-issue)

I have asked 1-2 questions here at stackoverflow, but apparently i'm on the wrong way approaching!
The issue is, i got this thing. I connect to the sql server like this:

```
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid, $passVal ) or die("Connection could not established");
```

It's supposed to use the database i've selected.
Now, here is how i do to select the table columns.

```
$result = mysql_query("DESCRIBE TABLE users");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($data);
```

Now, please someone guide me where i'm wrong, it's my first approach with this.
You may try to act "sarcastic, ironic" all you want, it would be rude.

My question is, why doesn't it recognize the database? apparently, that's the issue.
Thanks

Comment: As I said before on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13857256/1207346), mysql_* function are for mysql database, you need to either look into [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [sql server](http://php.net/sqlsrv)

Comment: You are very unclear with your question, I can't make out whether you're connecting AND using SQL server or if you're making an example of how SQL server php code works and MySQL php code doesn't work. As Dale said, you should use PDO, however if you don't get the desired results using mysql_query function - why aren't you checking for the error code that it gives? On failure mysql_query will return false and you can use mysql_error() to see what's wrong. You haven't provided us with that information so it's all wild guessing.

Comment: i tried using odbc like this: $res = odbc_exec($query);
i think it should be okay right?

Comment: N.B i know i am not clear, not because i don't want to be, but because i am not and i can't be..

The issue is, i have odbc drivers and i connect with it.. to the SQL Server, my question is, is it correct to use things like this? :
$res = odbc_exec($query);

Answer (score 2):

The `odbc_` methods have nothing to do with the `mysql_` methods. If you connect using `odbc_connect`, you need to use the `odbc_` methods to query the database. Calling any `mysql_` function makes it establish some default connection to the nearest default database, which is entirely separate from the previously established `odbc_` connection.

Guess what, you cannot query an **MS SQL server** using the **mysql** API.

Comment: Thanks, this is now clear to me..
it was simple as that!